# How to Log Complex Objects in NLog Connected to MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

I am trying to log custom complex objects in MongoDB using NLog in .NET Core 3.0.

An example would be:

```
 var customData = new { myData = "this is my data", test = new { fff = 1 } };
```

The problem is the logEventInfo.Properties only accepts string values which is weird and I would have to store JSON strings in MongoDb which makes MongoDB useless.

Are there any built-in solutions?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo, and you are right that it performs ToString on all properties: https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo/blob/ef7c48331d7a2a1e131ea270151ff1eb4495e531/src/NLog.Mongo/MongoTarget.cs#L301 . Since it is open-source-project then you are free to create a PullRequest to support converting properties into BsonDocument when it makes sense (With option to turn on/off). Happy coding

Comment: Any way, this is limitation of NLog.Mongo add on and not NLog itself. This means you could copy [the target class](https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo/blob/ef7c48331d7a2a1e131ea270151ff1eb4495e531/src/NLog.Mongo/MongoTarget.cs), include in your source and edit it to your liking - of course a PR would be nice :) Also check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target then

Comment: I have already fixed it but I need to create a pull request and push it.

Comment: @AmirH.Bagheri Sounds great. Will happily review a PullRequest for the NLog.Mongo-project (Or look at the code at your own Github-repository)

Comment: @RolfKristensen In a few days, I will. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @AmirH.Bagheri NLog.MongoDB-nuget-package have just been updated to improve connection-speed. You might be interested in updating your own custom build, by merging from the official github-repository.

Comment: @AmirH.Bagheri Have created a pull-request that enables support for converting into Json, and then parse as BsonDocument: https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo/pull/43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Mongo to version 4.6.0.118 or newer. Then you can do this (Notice the `bsonType="Object"`):

```
<target xsi:type="Mongo"
        name="mongoCustomJsonProperties"
        includeEventProperties="false"
        connectionString="mongodb://localhost/Logging"
        collectionName="CustomLog"
        cappedCollectionSize="26214400">
    <field name="Properties" bsonType="Object">
      <layout type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" includeMdlc="true" maxRecursionLimit="10">
        <attribute name="ThreadID" layout="${threadid}" encode="false" />
        <attribute name="ProcessID" layout="${processid}" encode="false" />
        <attribute name="ProcessName" layout="${processname:fullName=false}" />
      </layout>
    </field>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonSerializer then store it in the MongoDB this is the way you should do it:
Use Newtonsoft JsonSerializer or .Net core built-in serializer:

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customData );
// or var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(customData ); // .Net Core Serializer
logger.Log(result);
```

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good idea. Logging Frameworks doesn't expect log-message to preformatted in the Json-format. Usually one also also want to add extra meta-details (logger-name, loglevel, threadid, processid, machinename, etc). together with the customData-object and generate a single Json-Document.